# Can you view the Oracle listener status from OEM?

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

Is it possible to view/monitor the listener status from Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM)?  If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can view the listener status from OEM (Oracle Enterprise Manager).
I am uploading the two screen shot related to listener in Oracle 11g,OEM(Oracle Enterprise Manager) status.
[image]

and the current 'Up Status' of Listener.
[image]

**Note:** I have highlighted some part due to security reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Oracle Grid Control 11g OEM.

The listener is considered to be a target for monitoring.  Go to the Hosts tab, select a server and click on the Targets tab.

This will normally list all the database instances, the listeners and the OEM agent.

The status is indicated by the Availability column.

You can configure OEM to send you an email if the listener is down under the custom alerts configuration.

Comment: Oracle Database Control also has that view